# METHODS in switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

[image]

So I have an assignment to make program that does file manager job, I need first to enter Path to the file and after that enter method I want to use*info, create and stuff* so it does say f is already in use but how I fix this and make it work since I tried to change variable from f to x and program works but it doesn't find the file that is in its path

```
package file.manager;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileManager {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Unesi putanju");
    File f = new File(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Unesi funkciju");
    switch(sc.next()) 

{
case "info":
    File f = new File(sc.nextLine());
    if (f.exists())
        System.out.println(f.getName()+"exist!");
    else 
        System.out.println("this folder/file doesnt exist");
break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code becomes *much* easier to understand for yourself and other if you follow standard indentation:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Unesi putanju");
File f = new File(sc.nextLine());
System.out.println("Unesi funkciju");
switch(sc.next()) 
{
    case "info":
       File f = new File(sc.nextLine());
        if (f.exists())
            System.out.println(f.getName()+"exist!");
        else 
            System.out.println("this folder/file doesnt exist");
    break;
```

The following line exists twice in your code. (after `case "info":` and after `system.out.println`).

```
File f = new File(sc.nextLine());
```

Unless you want to take two separate paths and read two different files in the program, you should probably  remove the second one.